# React Hook Form is not submitting

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm new with react form, I'm using Material UI and Controller Component, and I'm sending a React Hook form request but not getting any response, form's (HTML form tag) onSubmit event is occurring but handleSubmit is not working **I have one more form like that it is working perfectly** fine but I don't know why it's not working, can anybody please help me with that

```
import { Button, useTheme, Grid, TextField, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import WSSelectBox from 'components/common/WSSelect';
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Controller, FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { isMobile } from 'utils/mediaqueries';
import CheckBoxButton from '../CheckBoxButton';
import { formTypes } from './utils';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { FormPropTypes } from './type';

const schema = yup
  .object()
  .shape({
    name: yup.string().required(),
    residentialCountry: yup.number().required(),
    initiator: yup.string().required(),
    program: yup.string().required(),
    list: yup.string().required(),
  })
  .required();

const Entities: FC<FormPropTypes> = ({
  handleClick,
  selectedType,
  handleSearch,
}) => {
  const theme = useTheme();

  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const { handleSubmit, control } = methods;
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // Backend is not done yet
    console.log('DataData', data);
  };
  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('skdjskd', 'Line no 44');
          handleSubmit(onSubmit);
        }}
      >
        <Grid container spacing={'16px'}>
          {formTypes.map((type) => (
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={'auto'} md={'auto'} key={type}>
              <CheckBoxButton
                key={type}
                name={'type'}
                value={type}
                handleClick={handleClick}
                active={type == selectedType ? true : false}
              />
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
        <Grid container pt={4} columnSpacing="20px" rowSpacing={'16px'}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={6}>
            <Controller
              name="name"
              render={({
                // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                field: { value, ...otherFieldProps },
                fieldState,
              }) => (
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  id="sanctions-form-name"
                  label="Name"
                  variant="outlined"
                  helperText={
                    <p
                      style={{
                        position: 'relative',
                        left: -13,
                        fontSize: 12,
                      }}
                    >
                      Try to enter the full name or part of it. It is possible
                      to use original language or the Latin alphabet.
                    </p>
                  }
                  required
                  error={!!fieldState.error}
                  {...otherFieldProps}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <WSSelectBox
              id="sanctions-form-residential-country"
              label="Residential country"
              name={'residentialCountry'}
              data={['Ten', 'Twenty']}
              handleSelect={() => {}}
              type={'text'}
              control={control}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}>
            <WSSelectBox
              data={['Ten', 'Twenty']}
              handleSelect={() => {}}
              id="sanctions-form-initiator"
              name={'initiator'}
              label="Initiator"
              type="text"
              control={control}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <WSSelectBox
              id="sanctions-form-program"
              label="Program"
              data={['Ten', 'Twenty']}
              handleSelect={() => {}}
              type="text"
              name={'program'}
              control={control}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6}>
            <WSSelectBox
              id="sanctions-form-list"
              label="List"
              data={['Ten', 'Twenty']}
              handleSelect={() => {}}
              type={'text'}
              name={'list'}
              control={control}
            />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          container
          pt={{ xs: '20px', md: '30px' }}
          rowSpacing="10px"
          alignItems="center"
          sx={{
            [isMobile(theme)]: {
              textAlign: 'center',
            },
          }}
          justifyContent="left"
        >
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={'auto'}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              sx={{
                minWidth: '200px',
                ['@media (max-width:460px)']: {
                  minWidth: '120px',
                },
              }}
              type="submit"
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={'auto'}>
            <Button
              sx={{
                minWidth: '200px',
                color: '#3883FA',
                ['@media (max-width:460px)']: {
                  minWidth: '120px',
                },
              }}
              type="submit"
            >
              Reset
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </form>
      <Typography
        variant="body2"
        sx={{ fontSize: 17, color: '#121E3D', marginTop: '20px' }}
      >
        Use filters to start your search.
      </Typography>
    </FormProvider>
  );
};

export default Entities;
```

SELECT BOX

```
import { TextField, MenuItem, styled, Select } from '@mui/material';
import { Controller, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
export type SelectBoxProps = {
  label: string;
  id: string;
  data: Array<string>;
  handleSelect: VoidFunction;
  type: string;
  Control: () => {};
};

const SelectBox = styled(TextField)`
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-root:focus {
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
      border-bottom: none !important;
    }
  }
`;

const WSSelectBox = ({
  label,
  id,
  data,
  handleSelect,
  name,
  type,
  control,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name={name}
        render={({ field }) => (
          <SelectBox
            defaultValue=""
            fullWidth
            autoComplete="off"
            id={id}
            type={type}
            label={label}
            variant="outlined"
            required
            select
            {...field}
          >
            {data.map((opt) => (
              <MenuItem key={opt} value={opt}>
                {opt}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </SelectBox>
        )}
        control={control}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default WSSelectBox;
```

Comment: seems onChange event is missing when you tries to set a value in dropdown

Comment: but I have an exact form, without onChange event and it is working fine

Comment: try to use onChange and set its value in state and at the time of submission use that state

Comment: Try adding an `onError` method and see if it's called on submitting form. You can pass `onError` as 2nd param to `handleSubmit`